# texnic center: pdf output doesn't display the specified paper size

Tags: latex

please help me. i just installed miktek and texnic center in my laptop. it works. however, im having problems when i set the papersize to legalpaper in the 
`\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}`.
it still displays the output using a letter paper. consequently, the bottom part of the document are cut-off and are not displayed.

Comment: This question should be moved to tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Maybe if you actually fill in `legalpaper` it will work better? (Or was this a copy/paste error, and your actual file does say `legalpaper` there?)

Answer (score 1):

Load the `geometry` package. This is needed because the standard classes don't set the PDF paper size properly. For a nice discussion see the [FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=papergeom).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't set a predefined paper size, you can try using something like this:

```
\setlength{\paperwidth }{8.5in}
\setlength{\paperheight }{14in}
```

Comment: @ivee There should be a legalpaper.* file somewhere. Maybe it is not there.